# TypeError: object dict can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, async-await, promise

I have a function that returns `MyResponse`

```
class MyClass:

    @staticmethod
    async def getQueryResponse(myData: MyData) -> MyResponse:
        queryObj = {
            "a": myData.a,
            "b": myData.b
        }
        queryResponse = await requests.post(URL_DEEP_LEARNING, json=queryObj).json()
        return queryResponse
```

Now in another class I am using it like

```
myResponse = await MyClass.getQueryResponse(data)
```

but this shows

```
TypeError: object dict can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Now if I remove the await

then it shows

```
value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

and when i used debugger to check the returned object from `MyClass`, it shows

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offending line is

```
queryResponse = await requests.post(URL_DEEP_LEARNING, json=queryObj).json()
```

change to

```
requests.post(URL_DEEP_LEARNING, json=queryObj).json()
```

returns a dict, and you are trying to await it.

`requests` is not an async pkg, you might want to check out aiohttp or httpx